# How to capture multiple groups in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to capture following word, number:

```
stxt:usa,city:14
```

I can capture usa and 14 using:

```
stxt:(.*?),city:(\d.*)$
```

However, when text is;

```
stxt:usa
```

The regex did not work. I tried to apply or condition using **|** but it did not work.

```
stxt:(.*?),|city:(\d.*)$
```

Comment: Maybe [`^stxt:(.*?)(?:,city:(\d.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hT2lW8/1)? Or do you want to also support `city:14` like strings with the same pattern? Split with a comma, and then with `:`, it will be easier.

Comment: This format of data might be better handled with some split, see also https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I want to support individual query both city and stxt. The regex you provided works for stxt but I am not able to understand it!

Comment: Well, you may also use [`(stxt|city):([^,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hT2lW8/2) regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works fine. thanks !

Comment: I added the answer then, with the pattern explanation and demos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
(stxt|city):([^,]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT2lW8/2) (note the `\n` added only for the sake of the demo, you do not need it in real life).

**Pattern details**:

- `(stxt|city)` - either a `stxt` or `city`  substrings (you may add `\b` before the `(` to only match a whole word) (Group 1)
- `:` - a colon
- `([^,]+)` - 1 or more characters other than a comma (Group 2).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/bOy5cN):

```
String s = "stxt:usa,city:14";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(stxt|city):([^,]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your string, you could also find the word/digits after the colon.

```
:(\w+)
```